# Magento- REST API/OAuth 3-legged authentication

Tags: php, magento, rest, oauth

While using Magento's REST API, it is madatory to make the calls validate through OAuth 3-legged authentication. The application from which i am trying to consume the services, i need for admin role REST user i by pass this authentication, can i do it?